# Problem with OneNote and SPO sync,

Tags: sharepoint-online, error, authentication, sync, onenote

I have a problem with OneNote and sync (and opening unsynced OneNote) with OneNote File stored in SharePoint Online.
I receive this error:

> Microsoft OneNote We couldn't open that location.*[OneNote URL]*  It
> might not exist or you might not have permission to open it.
>
> Please contact the owner of OneNote for more information. P1:
> 1099999

The problem surfaced few weeks ago, I managed to resolve it by deleting some old WindowsOneNote app. But now it surfaced again.

I do have access to site that stores the OneNote files, word files stored on same site open without any issue.

So far I tried:

1. Clear the OneNote Cache.
2. Clear the credentials (via Credentials Manager).
3. Disconnect AD account and connect it again.
4. Repair Office installation.
5. Removed OneNote tried to reconnect (got same error)
6. Some articles were pointing to Registry entries, but those were non-existent on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

Ok managed to resolve.
Point 2 (Clear the credential cache) had to be repeated, but I had to delete the credentials for other tenants, not only the one I had issue with.